# How to switch back and forth between two Word documents using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy / paste all words containing a specific text from the active word document to a new document. The problem is that I don't know how to deal with the second document properly, and all the pasting occur at the end of the first document, which is not what I want (since it is already a very large document).

The code I came out with is:

```
Sub FindWordCopySentenceToSecondDocument()
' the current document
    Dim aRange As Range
    Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range
' the new document
    Dim mWord As Object
    Set mWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    mWord.Visible = True
    mWord.Activate
    Dim NewDocument
    Set NewDocument = mWord.Documents.Add
    Dim docRng
    Set docRng = NewDocument.Range


    With aRange.Find
        Do
            .Text = "the one" ' the word I am looking for
            .Execute
            If .Found Then
                aRange.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
                aRange.Copy
                aRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                ' now copy to the other word. This is making problems!
                ' move the cursor to the end of the document:
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
                ' now paste, and insert also a carriage return:
                Selection.Paste
                Selection.TypeParagraph
            End If
        Loop While .Found
    End With
    Set aRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You are selecting and copying in `aRange` and then pasting in selection - ie the same range. You need to paste to `docRange`, your new document.

Comment: Olle Sjogren, I tried that, but the new paste will delete the old paste! I do not know how to paste at the end of a document...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to declare all your variables with the correct
   datatype. This will speed up the execution of the code and enable
   you to use IntelliSense when writing it.
2. There is no need to create a new instance of Word.
3. When using the `Range` object there is no need to use the
   clipboard as you can use the `FormattedText` property instead.
4. `.Find.Execute` returns a Boolean so there is no need to use the `Found` property
5. The `Find` settings should be outside of the loop.

   ```
   Sub FindWordCopySentenceToSecondDocument()
   ' the current document
       Dim aRange As Range: Set aRange = ActiveDocument.Range
   ' the new document
       Dim NewDocument As Document: Set NewDocument = Documents.Add
       Dim docRng As Range: Set docRng = NewDocument.Range

       With aRange
           .Find.Text = "the word" ' the word I am looking for
           Do While .Find.Execute
               aRange.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
               docRng.Characters.Last.FormattedText = aRange.FormattedText
               docRng.InsertParagraphAfter
               aRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
           Loop
       End With
       Set aRange = Nothing
   End Sub
   ```